# Comment traduire « in-place upgrade » : sur place ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, prépositions, informatique

En informatique on trouve le terme « [in-place upgrade](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/61018/in-place-upgrade) », une [*mise à niveau*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8390834) sans supprimer l'installation existante ni les données associées, généralement par opposition au « clean install » (l'installation complète, à partir de zéro). Dans une documentation on peut trouver « mise à niveau sur place ». On sait que « faire du sur [place](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/place) » c'est *ne pas avancer* et que quelqu'un qui fait quelque chose « sur [place](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/place) » le fait *sur les lieux, à l'endroit même* (TLFi).

Peut-on dire pourquoi on trouve ou non adéquat la « mise à niveau **sur place** » pour signifier ce dont il est question, en particulier en ce qui a trait au choix de la préposition [*sur*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sur) et vu le lexique et les locutions existantes ; utiliser la préposition *en* aurait-il été plus clair ; est-ce d'un emploi récent ; connaît-on un complément à *mise à niveau* qui soit plus explicite, significatif ou usuel en informatique que *sur place* ?

Comment: À mon avis *Mise à niveau* se suffit à lui-même. Je ne vois pas une *mise à niveau* (au sens informatique bien entendu) qui ne se fasse pas *in-place*, c'est redondant.

Comment: J'ai déjà lu l'expression *mise à jour incrémentale*, mais j'ignore si cela correspond exactement. Le *sur place* ne me choque pas, mais je ne suis pas informaticien. Une expression spécifique a sans doute été définie

Comment: Quand une machine A est en version 5, on peut créer une machine B en version 6, puis copier les données de A vers B. C'est aussi un mise à niveau. Dans ce cas on parle plutôt de **migration**. Une mise à niveau est implicitement sur place.

Comment: Pour compléter ce qui a été dit : l'article cité oppose *in-place upgrade* à *clean install*, pas à un simple *upgrade*. Donc *mise à niveau* doit suffire effectivement.

Comment: @Fólkvangr Tu avais vu juste, c'est bien une doc. de MS qui inspirait la question, donc ta réponse état utile pour compléter la question alors que je voulais tout simplement pas faire la promo. de MS. Peu probable qu'ils emploient G. Translate à Redmond. Finalement présenter la doc aurait permis de couper court aux trucs techniques : c'est de la doc de MS dont je parlais.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On trouve quelques rares *mise à niveau **in situ***.

Bien que la signification soit la même, à choisir, je préfère ***in situ*** à ***sur place*** ou ***sur site*** car ces derniers me semblent plus impliquer que l'équipement mis à niveau n'est pas temporairement déplacé vers un autre endroit (ex : un atelier de maintenance) pour effectuer la mise à niveau.

Comment: Peut-on faire une mise à niveau sur place à distance ?

Comment: @0ne1 Un *in-place upgrade* oui. Par exemple, les logiciels installés dans les satellites sont mis à niveau sans envoyer un technicien sur place ;-)

Comment: Ouais mais c'est encore drôle [néanmoins], parfois on voit des représentations d'astronautes et tu les vois changer une puce ou une carte en sortie dans l'espace etc. Finalement je ne suis pas certain de comprendre l'utilité de ça _sur place_-là. C'est la faute à MS.

Comment: @0ne1 Pas sûr que Microsoft soit à l'origine de l'expression. La plus ancienne que Google books trouve date de 1993 : *Using Novell NetWare 4* : *You use the in-place upgrade when you want to convert an existing Netware 2.x or 3.x server into a NetWare 4 server using the same hardware and the same disk volume configuration.* Sur place s'applique à l'emplacement occupé par le logiciel sur le disque, pour simplifier: on écrase les binaires en préservant les données. L'autre choix étant d'installer la nouvelle version à côté de l'ancienne, ce qui est moins risqué.

Comment: Donc sur place c'est à peu près « en lieu et place, à la place », spontanément je trouve pas ça évocateur ni clair mais là je comprends, merci. Ouais Novell, que de bons souvenirs de ça, la délégation des pouvoirs de gestion des répertoires à des « super-utilisateurs » j'avais trouvé ça vraiment brillant. Et j'aimais bien leur logo etc.